# django template / File name too long error/ when getting models objects

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting an error which lokks like this:

```
IOError at /url/
[Errno 36] File name too long: "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/

    <user_prefs: user_prefs object>,<user_prefs: user_prefs object>,<user_prefs: user_prefs object> etc..
```

my views.py look like this

```
def show_interests(request):
    current_user = request.user.id
    output = user_prefs()
    output.save()
    outputs = user_prefs.objects.all().filter(userID=current_user)
    return render('showme.html',{'outputs':outputs})
```

and my template( i use a very basic html form just to test things as for now.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hi, it's a test</title>
    {% for outputs in output %}
    {{ outputs.Cuisine }}
    {{ outputs.Cuisine1 }}
    {{ outputs.LunchPref }}
    {{ outputs.DinnerPref }}
    {{ outputs.Friday }}
    {{ outputs.Sunday }}
    {% endfor %}
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Never ever seen an error like this, and my other models that i have work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return render(request, 'showme.html',{'outputs':outputs})
```

you missed the `request` parameter in the `render` and its mandatory

and also change this in your template

```
{% for output in outputs %}
    {{ output.Cuisine }}
    {{ output.Cuisine1 }}
    {{ output.LunchPref }}
    {{ output.DinnerPref }}
    {{ output.Friday }}
    {{ output.Sunday }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you are welcome and also check the edited ans @pyjka

Answer (score 1):

Couple of mistakes in your view,

- As @Exprator pointed out, missed the `request` parameter.
- Your context variable is named as `outputs`, but in your template, you have written `{% for outputs in output %}` (may be just a typo).
- Every time you access this page an object is created. Probably, you don't want that.

Comment: hey, yea i removed the .save() line, i just wanted to make sure it also works like that whenever i visit the page, just testing things :p
and yea as @Exprator mentioned in his comment i changed the output vs outputs, but thanks a lot as well :)